# Why this htaccess not working

Tags: apache

This htaccess not working in server.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php/action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `'?'` not `'/'` when you are taking action parameter.

Replace last line with this code.

```
RewriteRule ([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Unless he is willing to use it as path info..in that case he needs to turn on `AcceptPathInfo On`